# When using a macro in Excel I get different results than when I do the tasks manually in the same sequence. Can you help fixing the macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have data from an external source imported into an excel sheet that contains date/time values but in a non standard format eg "25/02/2019 09:35AM"

Please note I am in UK so my default date format is dd-mm-yy not mm-dd-yy

When the data is imported into excel it is by default general format. To get it into usable date/time format I discovered that if I insert a space before the "AM" then the cell format gets changed to "custom" which in actual fact is a custom date time format which works exactly how I need it.

If I do this manually ie just edit the cell and insert a space it works as described above. If I do a search & replace (since I may have a list of 30 such cells with data in this format) and search for "AM" and replace with " AM" then it also works. (I have to do a second search and replace for "PM" of course)

However when I made a macro (with macro recorder) doing just the above described search and replace, the format for the cells gets changed to mm-dd-yy instead of dd-mm-yy and as you can imagine this destroys all my data.

I cannot figure out why this is and would be grateful for any help

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to do the conversion BEFORE the data is actually written to the worksheet.  You can do it as part of the import routine, using either VBA or Power Query.  Split the parts; create a date; then put the parts back together.

Answer (score 0):

You should  post your code.  Here is a really simple approach that takes the text in a cell, converts it into a real Excel Date/Time and stores the result to the adjacent cell:

```
Sub Konverter()
    Dim stuff As String
    Dim tPart As String, dPart As String
    Dim t As Date, d As Date

    stuff = ActiveCell.Text
    arr = Split(stuff, " ")
    dPart = arr(0)
    tPart = arr(1)

    tPart = Replace(Replace(tPart, "A", " A"), "P", " P")
    t = TimeValue(tPart)

    arr2 = Split(arr(0), "/")
    d = DateSerial(arr2(2), arr2(1), arr2(0))

    With ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
        .Value = d + t
    End With
End Sub
```

You will need to take something like this and put it in a loop or make a user defined function out of it.